# How to extract files from .CAB file using C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, cab

I have a CAB file generated from CABARC.EXE. I need to extract the file using ASP.Net C#.Net.

How to do it in C#.net itself? I don't want to use the same CABARC.EXE for extraction. Because we don't use this tool in production environment.

Please give your valuable suggestions/code to achieve this task.

Thanks in advance

Ganesh.

Answer (score 2):

I googled this for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CABCompressExtract.aspx

Looks like it does everything you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a native C# solution I suggest you start with the file specification for CAB files here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc483132(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: Hi tomfanning,

Thanks for you response.

Actually I'm a web guy and difficult to understand the core file specification. I couldn't write much new code for cab extraction. 

If possible give me the available solution.

Thanks
Ganesh.

Comment: So you need to find a library which does this, or hire someone to write one for you.

Comment: I found one for you. First result in Google.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb267310(v=vs.85)#microsoft-cabinet-file-format

There you have a file format description for the CAB file.